# How to plot a polynomial over a scatterplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

My intention is to plot a polynomial regression on a data

Lets say the x-axis is the third column of df that is `df[,3]` and the y-axis is fifth column `df[,5]`

I performed polynomial regression on this data and obtained a vector `yreg` which I want to plot over this scatter plot.

My question is how can we make it happen? All I have encountered so far are using built in regression models without explicitly defining the polynomial but in my case I have the regression polynomial in hand and I want to add it to the scatter plot of the x,y data

Here is how I plot the scatter plot using ggplot2

```
plt <- ggplot(g,aes(df[,3] , df[,5])) +
       geom_point(color = "#69b3a2",size=0.5)
```

I tried the following:

```
plt <- ggplot(g,aes(df[,3] , df[,5])) +
       geom_point(color = "#69b3a2",size=0.5) +
       geom_smooth(formula = y~yreg,color="red")
```

But that did not work.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Your code is not reproducible since we don't have your data.  "It didn't work" isn't specific.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I did receive an empty plot and this warning which is why I implied that it did not work: `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam'
Warning messages:
1: In predict.gam(model, newdata = data_frame(x = xseq), se.fit = se,  :
  not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!

2: 'newdata' had 80 rows but variables found have 70471 rows 
3: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 80, 70471   @Limey

Comment: For what it's worth, `mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()` gives sensible results for me.